# PHP Pagination Problem

Tags: php

I'm having a problem with my PHP pagination for a project.

It almost works but it doesn't seem to display the numbers correctly.

I want only 6 more page numbers to display after the selected and one before;
(also if you are on page one display **7 after**)

**For example:**

If on Page 1: **1**/2/3/4/5/6/7/8

If on Page 2: 1/**2**/3/4/5/6/7/8

If on Page 5: 4/**5**/6/7/8/9/10/11

If on Page 10: 9/**10**/11/12/13/14/15/16

**This is my code so far...**

```
if($page == ceil($NumOfPages) && $page != 1){
    for($i = 1; $i <= ceil($NumOfPages)-1; $i++){
    if($i > 0){
        echo "<a href=\"/{$i}\">{$i}</a>";
    }
    }
}
if ($page == ceil($NumOfPages) ) {
    $startPage = $page;
}else{
    $startPage = 1;
}
for ($i = $startPage; $i <= $page+6; $i++){
        if ($i <= ceil($NumOfPages)){
            if($i == $page) {
                echo "<a href='/page/$i/' title='View movies page $i' id='pagelisel'>$i</a> ";
            }else{
                echo "<a href='/page/$i/' title='View movies page $i' id='pageli'>$i</a> ";
            }
        }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you call 'ceil' on $NumOfPages, shouldn't it always be an integer? (I'm still reading your code, just thought I'd ask)

Comment: @TigerTrussell: probably due to something like `$NumOfPages=$posts/$postPerPage`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed that (partly for myself... ;) ):

- `$page` is the selected page
- `$startPage` is the first page number you want to show
- `$numPages` is already `ceil`-ed

First you need to find `$startPage`. Depending whether `$page` is the first one (ie has the value one 1, another assumption) or not. Your check is slightly off, as it check if it is equal to the last page.

```
if($page == 1) {
    $startPage = 1;
} else {
    $startPage = $page - 1;
}
```

Then you need to find out the last page number you want to print (`$lastPage`). So check if `$startPage` is near the end and set ~$lastPage` accordingly:

```
if($startPage + 7 > $numPages) {
    $endPage = $numPages;
} else {
    $endPage = $startPage + 7;
}
```

Finally, use you `for`-loop which seem ok, but loop from `$startPage` to `$endPage`.

Comment: You are a genius :) It's always a single character that messes the whole thing up, I can take it from here. Thanks Veger!

Comment: I misunderstood your code and my explanation is incorrect. I'll update my answer... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative approach that should work for you as well:

```
$pageCurrent = $page;
$pagePrevious = $pageCurrent-1;
$pageClass = '';
$pageStart = 1;
$pageEnd = $pageCurrent+6;
$pageMax = ceil($NumOfPages);

if($pageCurrent==1){
    echo "<a href=\"/page/1\" class=\"selected\">1</a>";
}else{
    echo "<a href=\"/page/$pagePrevious\">$pagePrevious</a>";
}

for($i = $pageStart; $i <= $pageEnd; $i++){
    if($i <= $pageEnd){
        if($i == 1 && $pageCurrent != 1){
            $pageClass = 'selected';
        }else{
            $pageClass = '';
        }
        echo "<a href=\"/page/$i\" title=\"View movies page $i\" class=\"$pageClass\">$i</a>";
    }
}
```

Comment: In your `for`-loop after one number got selected, all following numbers are also selected.